# Error 310 too many redirects after switching domains

Tags: errors, redirect

I'm at a loss here. My site is http://www.kgstiles.com and about 70% of my pages now result in a 310 error. There doesn't seem to be any pattern to the error, but one thing I thought was interesting: if I change the slug of a page, it works, but obviously I can't do that for all of them.

I tried rebuilding the .htaccess file, saving the permalink structure again, I have restored all files from a few days ago before switching the domain, then I restored the database - none of it worked. I have tried installing "Permalink Fix & Disable Canonical Redirects Pack" which solved the problem for some people and tried one more plugin that solved the issue for others(can't think of the name at the moment).

What could be the problem? Nothing has changed in Wordpress.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+
RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^wp-content(/.*|)$ - [L] # don't take any action
RewriteRule ^wp-admin(/.*|)$ - [L] # don't take any action
RewriteRule ^wp-includes(/.*|)$ - [L] # don't take any action

RewriteRule ^moreinfo/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/moreinfo$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^healthsolutions/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/healthsolutions$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1/ [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is infinitely redirecting. I have seen (and created) this problem a lot when trying to do either a non-www to www domain or a non-trailing-slash to trailing-slash redirect. Did you or an SEO firm do 301 redirects after a new site launch and can you post the contents of your .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes I did, but we've switched the domain name twice since the .htaccess has been edited without any problems. I'll post it in an edit of my answer above.

Comment: The first thing that jumps out to me is the lack of an L flag on those redirects. For 301 redirects as you are doing there I typically include the flags [NC,L,R=301]

Comment: I changed the [R=301]'s to [NC,L,R=301] and it didn't help. I am a little concerned because I did an http header check on one of the pages that is giving me the 310 which is registering as a 301 redirect to http://www.kgstiles.com/missing/. WHere could /missing/ be coming from?