# My wordpress site must be being affected by outside sources

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, database, redirect, errors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error 310 too many redirects after switching domains](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78296/error-310-too-many-redirects-after-switching-domains)

Some of my pages are resulting in 310 errors. We recently switched domains from kgstiles.com to healthmasterysystems.com then discovered healthmasterysystems.com was listed as not trust-worthy by google and really strange popups kept coming up. Google had had a malicious site warning dating back to March - long before we got it, so yesterday we switched it back.

if you go to http://www.kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/, it redirects to kgstiles.com/missing/. I have installed all sorts of plugins to stop it, I have changed the permalink structure, cleared htaccess, repaired the database etc..etc.. nothing ever worked, so I restored the database and all of the files to before we switched domains and the problem still persisted! Is it safe to assume something outside of the website is affecting it? What could possibly be happening?

Comment: Please stop asking almost the same question again and again. Improve the first question instead, start with an explanation for _310 error_. A 3xx status is never an error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you got a recycled domain and/or your hosting configuration is not configured right. Also by running a traceroute you have multiple domains set for both http://www.kgstiles.com & http://www.kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials This is a pretty common scenario but can sometimes cause some domain issues.

I wouldn't rule you the possibility of some external source affecting your site but it also wouldn't be my first consideration.

Have you tried accessing that URL with a dummy directory to see if it still redirects?

Comment: A dummy directory?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: You could create a directory matching the name pureplantessentials inside your Wordpress directory. Then put a regular .html file inside of it to test if it's Wordpress or your server setup that's causing the issue.